# Clojure using let variable declaration within its own instantiation?

Tags: list, clojure

In the language of Clojure I am trying to pass a variable that I am defining within a `let` as a parameter to a function within the same `let`. The variable itself represents a list of vectors representing edges in a graph. The function I want to pass it to uses the list to make sure that it does not generate the same value within the list.

The function in whole

```
(defn random-WS 
  ([n k] (random-WS (- n 1) k (reg-ring-lattice n k)))
  ([n k graph] 
   (cond (= n -1) graph
         :else
         (let [rem-list (for [j (range (count (graph n))) :when (< (rand) 0.5)]
                          [n (nth (seq (graph n)) j)])
               add-list (for [j (range (count rem-list))]
                          (random-WSE graph n add-list))
               new-graph (reduce add-edge (reduce rem-edge graph rem-list) add-list)]
           (random-WS (- n 1) k new-graph)))))
```

The actual problem statement is seen here

```
add-list (for [j (range (count rem-list))]
    (random-WSE graph n add-list))
```

Again for clarity, the function `random-WSE` generates a random edge for my graph based on some rules. Given the current `graph`, current node `n`, and current list of edges to add `add-list` it will generate one more edge to add to the list based on some rules.

The only real idea I have is to first `let` `add-list ()` to first define it before then redefining it. Though this still has somewhat the same issue, though `add-list` is now defined, it will be `()` through out the `for` statement. Thus the function `random-WSE` will not take into account the edges already in the list.

Is there a way to "evaluate" `add-list` at some defined point within its own definition so that it can be used, within its definition? So I would first "evaluate" it to `()` before the `for` and then "evaluate" after each iteration of the `for`.

If you're interested the function is used to create a random [Watts-Stogatz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watts_and_Strogatz_model) graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I get of your description of this algorithm, add-list grows (accumulates) during the problematic for loop. Accumulation (for a very broad acceptation of accumulation) is a strong sign you should use `reduce`:

`(reduce (fn [add-list j] (conj add-list (random-WSE graph n add-list))) [] (range (count rem-list))`

Answer (score 0):

Basically you're chaining results in your `let`, in the sense that the result of the first computation (resulting in `rem-list`) is the sole input for your second computation (your trouble point) which again is the sole input for your third computation, which is finally the sole input to your final computation step (your recursion step). If this chaining sounds familiar, that's because it is: think about reformulating your `let` construction in terms of the threading macro `->`.

I.e. something along the lines of

```
(defn- rem-list [graph n]
   ...)
(defn- add-list [remlist n]
   ...)
(defn- new-graph [addlist]
   ...)

(defn random-ws 
   ([n k] ...)
   ([graph n k] ;; <- note the moved parameter
     (cond (= n -1) graph
           :else    
           (-> graph
               (rem-list n)
               (add-list n)
               (new-graph)
               (random-ws (dec n) k))))
```

You can then formulate `add-list` as a simple recursive function (maybe introduce an accumulator variable) or use the `reduce` variant that cgrand explained.